# How to mask inputs using cocoon gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I have an javascript like this:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
 $('#client_phone').mask('(00)00000-0000');
});
```

It works only for the first element, when I click on "add new fields", the mask doesn't apply. So I tried using cocoon callbacks, like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
 $('#phone_clients').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
  $('#client_phone').mask('(00)00000-0000');
 });
});
```

But it doesn't work, I have tested using alert('something') inside the callback and it has appeared. So I have no idea why the mask isn't applying.

Could you guys, please, help me?

Comment: when you add a new field, `#client_phone` **id** appeared twice in the DOM. So, when you mask it always mask the first element. you need to use `$(this).find('#client_phone')` maybe in after-insert callback

Comment: $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#phone_clients').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    $(this).find('#client_phone').mask('(00)00000-0000');
  });
});

Comment: @Emu did that and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   $('#phone_clients').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
      $(insertedItem).find('#client_phone').mask('(00)00000-0000');
   });
});
```